# Javascript moving circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I need to program a html-based monitoring surface.

For the surface I need to code circles which move from x to y and only if number xy is greater than xy. 
Hard to explain but actually similar like they have it on

https://www.solarweb.com

click "click to try the preview now" on the top, than click "view demo" and choose the first system "Fronius AT Sattledt Hybrid 2"

and see the animation above on the left side.

I´ve still been able to get a circle running from the beginning of a div to the end. but only 1 circle! is it possible to have more circles in a row doing the same?

Maybe anyone can help me :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Moving Bullet</title>
    <meta charset="utf8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #energieFluss {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;

    }

    #bullet {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    }
    </style>
```

```
<body>

<div id="energieFluss" width="900px" height="500px" color="red">
    <img id="bullet" src="ball-blau.png" height ="25" width= "25">
    </div>
<script>

        var Bullet = document.querySelector ("#bullet");
        var currentPos = 0;

        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


        function moveBullet () {
            currentPos += 8;


            Bullet.style.left = currentPos + "px";


            if (Math.abs(currentPos) >= 900) {
            currentPos = -50;
            }


            requestAnimationFrame(moveBullet);

        }
        moveBullet ();

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work. I get a session related failure.

Comment: oh oke, sorry, maybe try the start page: https://www.solarweb.com/

Comment: than click solarweb prewiev on the top, than view demo and than choose the first system (Fronius AT Sattledt Hybrid 2)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll want to do here is create your image elements on the fly and then animate them. You could also do other fancy things like render on a canvas or use a JavaScript rendering library to do it more efficiently.

To create the elements on the fly, do something like this:

```
var balls = [];

// Run this in a loop to add each ball to the balls array.
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "ball-blau.png";
img.height = 25;
img.width = 25;
document.getElementById("energieFluss").appendChild(img);
balls.push(img)
```

**Post thought:**

You could just statically define your image elements and animate multiple elements. If you already know how to animate one element, then you can apply that same knowledge to multiple.